# Fatal error: Call to undefined function gmp_sign() in php

Tags: php

I have tried to use gmp_sign in my file to find the sign of the value, but i getting an error like call to undefined function with fatal error.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/gmp.installation.php

Comment: [Voting to close as this has already been asked on SF.](https://serverfault.com/questions/429585/how-to-install-enable-gmp-math-functions-for-php-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it Ubuntu/Linux?
Seems like GMP is not installed on the system. Follow these steps:

1. Installed GMP with `apt-get install php5-gmp`
2. Added `extension=php_gmp.so` to php.ini

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gmp_sign` as below:

Installed GMP with:

```
apt-get install php5-gmp
```

Added:

```
extension=php_gmp.so to php.ini
```