# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Admin\gmp_intval()

Tags: reactjs

Problems Images

[image: 1]

I installed the website, but whenever I try to add some categories it gives me an error like this?

I have tried to change the PHP version and change some files in the .env file of the code but does not fix my problems.

Comment: Are you sure this is a reactjs issue? From the screenshot and your comment, it seems that it's a PHP issue (Larvel?). Also, avoid posting screenshots of errors and code, and post code instead. Regarding the actual error - [does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647745/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-gmp-sign-in-php)?

Answer (score 0):

check for an extension named GMP if either it is enable or not. if you are on local machine enable it in php.ini
go to your php.ini file and find for GMP and remove semicolon before it.

[like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYlCJ.png)

and If you're using a hosting company then you should contact their support to see if they can enable it for you (or give you instructions on how to enable it yourself).

Comment: yes, I have enabled the GMP extension on a Main domain, But I run this website on Subdomain. So how can I enable GMP for the subdomain from Cpanel?

Comment: search for PHP PEAR Packages or MultiPHP INI Editor in your cpanel search bar you can manage all you extensions from there.